Bash: programmatically output text to cursor?
I'm trying to cook up a script to use OpenAI's Whisper as a speech-to-text. The basic idea is I press some key combination, it starts recording to an audio file somewhere, I stop it, it analyzes the audio and gets the text from it, and then it pastes all this text directly to my cursor in whatever program I was using. It's this last part I don't know how to do - I can output it to the clipboard, but that's still an extra couple keypresses to paste and I want it to be as smooth as possible. Is there a way to do what I want?
EDIT: here is the complete script, which you can modify as necessary.
#!/bin/bash
gunchislas() (
    echo $BASHPID > [scripts path]/pid.txt
    arecord -f cd -D "default" --file-type raw | lame -r - "[scripts path]/.stt.mp3"
)
waiting() {
    zenity --info --text="Taking speech to text input now."
}
gunchislas & waiting & wait -n
pkill -P $(cat [scripts path]/pid.txt) --signal 9
aplay "[scripts path]/clock.wav"
whisper "[scripts path]/.stt.mp3" --language en --model tiny | cut -c 28- | awk NF=NF RS= OFS=" " | xclip
rm "[scripts path]/.stt.mp3"
rm "[scripts path]/pid.txt"
aplay "[scripts path]/recorded.wav" & xdotool type "$(xclip -o)"

clock.wav and recorded.wav are just little notification sounds I made so you can tell what it's doing

Which Ubuntu version? Or, rather, Xorg or Wayland? Easy to do with xdotool, hard to do (at least in my experience) using ydotool. If you're on Wayland, you may try your luck with ydotool, personally I couldn't get the thing to work.

xdotool got it! i used xdotool type "$(xclip -o)" and now i have a complete speech to text system on my laptop!!!! sorry for exclamation marks i'm very excited

I'm glad you got it to work! But please don't post answers as edits to your question, answer your own question instead

To programatically output text at the cursor, one can use keyboard simulation tools. These tools send keystrokes to an application.
xdotool type "$(xclip -o)" may indeed appear to be a way to make it work. However:

It will only work on Xorg, not on Wayland, the default of modern Ubuntu systems.

It will prove to be unreliable when the text to type becomes somewhat longer: there is a chance that keystrokes get lost.



To address issue one, you can use ydotool or dotool. These tools work on both Xorg and Wayland. To manipulate the clipboard on Wayland, wl-clipboard is available.

To address issue two, consider pasting the clipboard text rather than typing it. To do that, simulate the shortcut key Ctrl+V or Shift+Insert. Not only will that reliably paste all text, it will also be a lot faster.


In your script, the text is already in the clipboard. So pasting rather than typing the contents out is obvious: you can simply replace xdotool type "$(xclip -o) with xdotool key ctrl+v. Using dotool, the command will be:
echo key ctrl+v | dotoolc
With ydotool, it becomes
ydotool key 29:1 47:1 47:0 29:0

I do quite like the animation of it typing the full string out, but if it's genuinely more reliable the other way I suppose it's an improvement. I'm now using xdotool click 2 for this; I'll approach the wayland issue when I move to wayland

gave up on xdotool click 2 because it was super inconsistent. now i have the script writing the previous contents of the clipboard (including the correct mime type) to a file, passing the transcription through the regular ctrl V clipboard, then restoring the original contents of the clipboard back from the file.
